# Android Kotlin : How to login with Internet in the first time and then locally (with details saved locally)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, authentication, local-storage

I work with Kotlin and Android Studio and have made a login page and a dashboard

I want my user log in app with internet (this means in the first time his details will be checked with my database) and after that, if his information is true , I want my application to save his username and password locally

So for example when he want to log in app 10 days later, he does not need to connect the internet to log in; and he will be able to log in locally

How can I do that?

(I have been working on Kotlin for a while now! so you will have my thanks if you do not recognize my question useless!)

Comment: "he does not need to connect the internet to log in; and he will be able to log in locally" -- what does "log in locally" mean?

Comment: If just one time login is enough, you can use data store to save if user logged in successfully or not and check it's status when the app is starting. I suggest to use access tokens you can make a research on it

Comment: @CommonsWare "log in locally" means his user and pass is saved somewhere in his phone and app uses only the phone to check user and pass

Comment: @BurakKaraduman if you explain that with code it will be appreciated

Comment: What is the significance of being "logged in"? Do you continue to make calls to a server while the user is logged in? In that case you would record a token locally, not the password.

Comment: @Tenfour04 My users My users may be in a place where they do not have access to the internet, depending on their circumstances, So your explanation with code will be appreciated

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the task--I'm not sure you understood my question. Does being logged in mean you are permitted to make requests and receive data from a server, or does it only mean some local features are enabled or not?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have a login page and a dashboard page
After installation, I want my user log in with internet
In the next times, I want him be able to log in without internet

Answer (score 0):

If you get an auth token when login via username and password you can save it locally in sharedpreferences and check on startup of the app that it is blank or not. If token is blank then you have to show login page otherwise you have to to navigate user to mainactivity of your app.

If you don't have auth token then you have to save username and password in sharedpreferences but this is not the recommended approach as it might have security concerns.

Comment: How can I get an auth token?

Comment: This should be done on backend.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the relevant code?